# React Native how to navigate to a Screen and reset some of the states?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-state

again, I need some help. I am trying to implement a shopping cart for my application.

The application has the following logic:

```
BarcodeScreen (params) => MenuScreen loads data from params => CheckoutScreen
```

The problem is, that I want to have a "Reset" button, to remove all products in the cart.
For that reason on my CheckoutScreen, there is a Reset button, which navigates to the previous screen (MenuScreen) and it needs to reset some of the state variables (the params for loading data must stay).

Here is the MenuScreen code:

```
function MenuScreen({ route, navigation }) {
    const params = route.params;

    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const [length, setLength] = useState(0);

    useEffect( () => {
        loadMenu();
    }, []);

    const loadMenu = async () => {
        const response = await MenuApi.getMenu(params.data);
        if(!response.ok) Alert.alert(response.data.message);
        setLoading(false);
        setProducts(response.data.data);
    }

    const addItem = (item) => {
        items.push(item);
        setLength(items.length);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <View style={styles.activity}>
                <ActivityIndicator animating={loading} size="large"/>
            </View>
            <FlatList 
                data={products}
                ...
            />
            <View style={styles.activity}>
                <Text>You have {length} products in your order</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.activity}>
                <Button title="View Basket" onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Checkout", items)}></Button>
            </View>
        </>
    );
}
```

That is the CheckoutScreen code:

```
function CheckoutScreen({ route, navigation }) {
    const products = route.params;

    return (
        <>
        <View style={styles.activity}>
            <FlatList 
                data={products}
                ...
            />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.activity}>
            <Button title="Submit"></Button>
            <Button title="Reset" onPress={() => navigation.reset({
                index: 0,
                items: [],
                routes: [{ name: "Menu"}]
            })}>
            </Button>
        </View>
        </>
    );
}
```

Now, when I go back to the MenuScreen, the items = 0, but I don't have the params data anymore.

Comment: Why instead of using navigation.reset you do perform a navigation.navigate("MenuScreen", items)}?

Comment: The `useEffect` which calls ` loadMenu()` has an empty dependency array, meaning that it is only called once.  So `products` will not be updated when `params.data` changes.

Comment: Also, if you want to keep all params when going back to the menu, include the current params in your navigation call `...route.params`

Comment: @LindaPaiste 1) do I need to change something in useEffect? 2) to use navigation.reset() or navigation.navigate() 3) if I need to use reset(), how to pass the route.params?

Comment: Do you have a repo or a CodeSandbox that you can share? It's easier for me to play with things that way.  I'm more familiar with react-router than react-navigation but they are similar.   When you go back to the component screen, it gets its items from its own internal state and disregards the `params.items`, so you would need an effect to sync them.  But that feels sloppy and I think that passing the `MenuScreen` component state back and forth via navigation is not what you want to do.  I would try to move the state up a level to a `Page` or `App` component. Maybe access via context.

Comment: Shopping carts often store some data in the browser's `localStorage` so that it remembers the contents in a new window or a new session.

Answer (score 0):

MenuScreen and CheckoutScreen are two different screens each with their own state. If you want both screens to share that state and both manipulate it and for the state to persistent between them, I recommend you to use
[React Redux](https://redux.js.org/) for the job.